# Error: File validation failed: content: Path `content` is required., title: Path `title` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I'm trying trying to add text data in the database and display it on the dashboard. I have created a separate route for adding files.
I'm following Brad's video: [NodejsfromScratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBvmnHTQIPY&t=4040s)
I'm currently stuck at Add files part (1:31:24)

When I enter the text data in the add files form, I get this error:

```
Error: File validation failed: content: Path `content` is required., title: Path `title` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)
    at internal/per_context/primordials.js:23:32
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:783:19)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:337:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:2016:40)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1898:10)
    at console.value (internal/console/constructor.js:330:14)
    at console.warn (internal/console/constructor.js:363:61)
    at E:\EXP_NP\BT\routes\files.js:24:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errors: {
    content: ValidatorError: Path `content` is required.
        at validate (E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1253:13)
        at E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1236:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1181:14)
        at E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2517:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'content',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    title: ValidatorError: Path `title` is required.
        at validate (E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1253:13)
        at E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1236:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1181:14)
        at E:\EXP_NP\BT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2517:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'title',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'File validation failed'
}
```

My Files schema: *(models/files)*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
        trim: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('File', fileSchema);
```

My Files route: *(routes/files)*

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { ensureAuth } = require('../middleware/auth')
const File = require('../models/Files')

// @desc    Show add page
// @route   GET /files/add
router.get('/add', ensureAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('files/add', {
        layout: 'add',
        title: 'Add',
    })
})

// @desc    Process add form
// @route   POST /files
router.post('/', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
   try {
        req.body.user = req.user.id
        await File.create(req.body)
        res.redirect('/dashboard')

   } catch (err) {
       console.error(err);
       res.render('error/500')
   }
})

module.exports = router
```

My app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const path = require("path")
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars")
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

// DATABASE CONNECTION
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const { connection } = require('mongoose')

// Load config
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })

//Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport)

connectDB()

const app = express()

// Body Parser 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())

// Handlebars
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main', 
    extname: '.hbs', 
    partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/',
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts'
}))
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


// Express Session Middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI, collection: 'sessions' }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 1 Day
    }
}))

// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routes
app.use('/',require('./routes/index'))
app.use('/users',require('./routes/users'))
app.use('/files',require('./routes/files'))

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
// app.set("views", template_path);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

My html file: *(views/files/add)

```
 <form action="/files" method="POST">
      <div class="form">
        <p>
          <label>Title <span>*</span> </label>
          <input type="text" class="field size" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Content <span>*</span> </label>
          <textarea name="body" id="body" class="field size" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">
      </div>
    </form>
```

My layout file: *(views/layouts/add)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Add Files</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/add.css" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{{body}}}

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.16.0/ckeditor.js" integrity="sha512-7My1gsUz5JUQgT8+P0sHKaPel/77X3zjGZsXbTS8Y7MhDEJ+f9xg9H+pPzONFL5djye0zWLlxFLApGsWQ1gdfA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('body', {
        plugins: 'wysiwygarea, toolbar, basicstyles, link'
      })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My Input:

***Title***: *Lorem Ipsum*
***Content***: *Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.*

Comment: Are you using body-parser or express.json to parse the body? show app.js and the html form please they would help

Comment: I have added the files now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title input doesn't have a name and your textarea is named body.
Add `name="title"` to input and change textarea name to `content`

```
<form action="/files" method="POST">
  <div class="form">
    <p>
      <label>Title <span>*</span> </label>
      <input name="title" type="text" class="field size" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Content <span>*</span> </label>
      <textarea name="content" id="body" class="field size" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have made correction in the html but still facing the same issue

Comment: Can you update the code and `console.log(req.body)` in your route?

Comment: I have added `name` to the inputs & my textarea is named body to change it to a **CKEDITOR** textbox. So I have changed the input to `body` instead of `content`

Comment: I got rid of the body error. When I `console.log(req.body)`. I got the body But my title is `undefined`. How do I fix it?

Comment: `<input name="title" type="text" class="field size" />` you named your input title like this?

Comment: `<input name="title" id="title" type="text" class="field size" />`. Yes

Comment: try `console.log(req.body.title)` and see if it returns the title

Comment: also in ckeditor why do you need to name the textarea body? ckeditor only uses the id right?

Comment: I got the title.

Comment: CKEDITOR uses `name` field I think. Don't know for sure !!

Comment: Can you try the form like the code snippet above and see if it works, because it should work with no issues

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now I can successfully store the text data into the database but I can't display it on the dashboard.

Comment: To display it you would need to make get route that uses mongoose .find and render the data on the view

Comment: Thanks man !! Now everything is working fine !!